# Каким образом можно ускорить загрузку сайта https://tex-izol.ru/ по гугл PageSpeed?

Tags: битрикс

Каким образом можно ускорить загрузку сайта  https://tex-izol.ru/ по гугл  PageSpeed ? Сайт на битрикс

Answer (score 1):

Открываем исходник префикс "viewsource:" `view-source:https://tex-izol.ru/`

1. В сайте огромное количество пробелов в коде - убераем.
2. Тэги `<script>` и `style` с кодом, убираем (Они не кэшируются!)
3. Все `<link href="/bitrix/cache/css/s1/texizol/page_3d3 ...` совершенно не сжаты, используем постпроцессоры с сжатием.
4. Слишком много CSS и JS файлов которые разбросаны по разным источникам. Так-же сжимаем постпроцессором CSS/JS и делаем в один файл **с включенным кэшем** и **GZ сжатием**
5. Очень много лишних элементов `<div class="col-lg-4...col-xs-12"><div class="contactemail">` див внутри дива - убираем лишние блоки. оставляем строго необходимые семантические.
6. `height="66" width="80" alt="logo" class="header-logo"` разметка размеров должна находиться в CSS, `alt` и `title` должны быть логический осмысленными `логотип компании геотехизол`
7. `alt="" class="frontpage-product-image" loading="lazy"` пустой атрибут `alt` , `loading` неподдерживаемый атрибут в HTML5 стандарте. Используйте `data-*` атрибуты.
8. Теги с метрикой и прочие неиспользуемые при загрузке должны иметь атрибут `async` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp

Я тут уже на половине заработал 500$ как SEO специалист... Думаю в идеальности нанять SEO спеца, и дать ему денег.